# Joining two tables based on criteria across multiple columns

Tags: r, join, merge

I am working with GPS collar data from wildlife.  GPS collars are identified by serial number.  A single GPS collar may be used for multiple animals over the course of a few years.  I need to assign animal ID to each data point from a GPS collar.  Animal ID should be assigned to the correct collar number, but only for locations taken on or after the capture date and on or before the mortality date (if applicable) of that animal.

The following is an example of what my data look like.

When the GPS collar data is downloaded via satellite it is in the following format:

```
   CollarSerialNumber Latitude Longitude       Date
1               36542 44.95511 -107.5431 2016-02-18
2               36542 44.94927 -107.5855 2016-02-19
3               36542 44.95027 -107.5838 2016-02-20
4               36542 44.96125 -107.5831 2016-02-20
5               36542 44.95949 -107.5854 2016-02-21
6               36542 44.95233 -107.5717 2016-02-21
7               36542 44.95743 -107.5664 2016-02-22
8               36542 44.96124 -107.5840 2016-02-22
9               36542 44.96322 -107.5799 2016-02-22
10              36542 44.95912 -107.5857 2016-02-23
11              36545 44.95263 -107.5207 2016-02-17
12              36545 44.95278 -107.5202 2016-02-17
13              36545 44.95366 -107.5481 2016-02-18
14              36545 44.93453 -107.5940 2016-02-19
15              36545 44.94563 -107.5823 2016-02-19
16              36545 44.95020 -107.5836 2016-02-20
```

I have a separate data frame that contains capture dates of animals (i.e. the date the collar was deployed on the animal), animal IDs, and mortality dates.

```
  Animal_ID Collar_Serial Capture_Date  Mort_Date
1    16-046         36542   2016-02-18 2016-02-20
2    16-047         36542   2016-02-21         NA
3    16-048         36545   2016-02-17         NA
```

So I need to add an Animal_ID column to the GPS collar data that indicates Animal_ID, based on the Collar Serial # and Capture and Mortality Dates. My expected output would be the following:

```
   CollarSerialNumber Latitude Longitude       Date    Animal_ID
1               36542 44.95511 -107.5431 2016-02-18    16-046 
2               36542 44.94927 -107.5855 2016-02-19    16-046 
3               36542 44.95027 -107.5838 2016-02-20    16-046 
4               36542 44.96125 -107.5831 2016-02-20    16-046 
5               36542 44.95949 -107.5854 2016-02-21    16-047
6               36542 44.95233 -107.5717 2016-02-21    16-047
7               36542 44.95743 -107.5664 2016-02-22    16-047
8               36542 44.96124 -107.5840 2016-02-22    16-047
9               36542 44.96322 -107.5799 2016-02-22    16-047
10              36542 44.95912 -107.5857 2016-02-23    16-047
11              36545 44.95263 -107.5207 2016-02-17    16-048
12              36545 44.95278 -107.5202 2016-02-17    16-048
13              36545 44.95366 -107.5481 2016-02-18    16-048
14              36545 44.93453 -107.5940 2016-02-19    16-048
15              36545 44.94563 -107.5823 2016-02-19    16-048
16              36545 44.95020 -107.5836 2016-02-20    16-048
```

Comment: Did you try anything at all? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Your question is not clear (to me). Does `Date` from the GPS data need to match `Capture_Date` or `Mort_Date`? Can you please edit your question to include your expected output for the sample data you give.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I have edited the question with expected output.  Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: @MrFlick I searched forums for people who have had similar issues, and read up on merge and join functions, but I failed to make any progress...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a rather clunky solution to my problem, but it works.  See below:

```
#get all Animal_IDs from capture dataset
allID = unique(capdat$Animal_ID)

#create list to hold data frames, one df for each animalID
df.list <- as.list(rep("", length(allID)))

#loop through each animal ID, find matching collar serial #, capture date, 
#and mortality date (if applicable)
for (i in 1:length(allID)){
  ID.i = allID[i]
  ser.i <- pull(capdat[capdat$Animal_ID == ID.i, 4])
  capdate.i = pull(capdat[capdat$Animal_ID == ID.i, 2])
  mortdate.i = pull(capdat[capdat$Animal_ID == ID.i, 11])

  ifelse(is.na(mortdate.i), 
        df.list[[i]] <- dat[(dat$CollarSerialNumber == ser.i & 
                          dat$Date > capdate.i) ,],
        df.list[[i]] <- dat[(dat$CollarSerialNumber == ser.i & 
                          dat$Date > capdate.i & dat$Date < mortdate.i) ,])
  df.list[[i]]$Animal_ID = ID.i
  }

#merge list into a single data frame
df <- ldply(df.list, data.frame)
```

If anyone can come up with a more elegant solution, I would love to see it!